# safari redirect re-caching resources

Tags: iframe, browser, safari, cross-domain, browser-cache

I am using a hidden iframe on my page (a.html) to prefetch resources from a landing page (b.html). On chrome, firefox, and IE, a.html prefetches and caches resources (jpeg, gif, etc) in the browser cache as expected. However, Safari does not cache properly, and instead GET's the resources on both a.html, and b.html, even though the resources are the same (a.html calls b.html's resources in the hidden iframe)

Does safari handle cross domain caching differently? Is there something different that goes on with Safari's caching method in iframes?